# Can we apply animation to a specific child and not the entire root in android

Tags: android, animation, inflate

Below is my code example: 
I inflated a view and want to add animation to only the inflated one. Right now its doing for the entire layout.

```
    LinearLayout lLay = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.FirstContact);
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(50);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
    );
    animation.setDuration(500);
    set.addAnimation(animation);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                lLay.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.genericrelativelayout, null, false), position);
                lLay.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you just want to call `View.setAnimation()` on your inflated view, and not bother with  `LayoutAnimationController`?

Comment: I tried doing something like this, but failed
      
RelativeLayout rlay = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.layout.genericrelativelayout);

rlay.setAnimation(set);

Can you put some more light on this?
Thanks!!

Comment: What does "failed" mean? It crashes? Nothing happens? If the latter, try rlay.startAnimation() instead, or anim.start();

Comment: Thanks!!! But no effect of setStartOffSet(). I have a loop to inflate views depending on the count. So say if my count is 3, 3 views are inflated. I want a delay in animation between each child...so that they are listed below each other after a short time delay...